# PowershellからPythonのdefに引数を渡したい

Tags: python, powershell

PowershellからPython(ver.3.8.1)のdefに引数を渡して実行したいのですが、
うまく渡すことができません。
今回、初めてPythonを使います。
テストで下記のような簡単な関数を作ってみました。
実行すると

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

というエラーが発生します。
ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いします。

**calc.py**

```py
def add(a):
    return 10 + a
```

**main.py**

```py
from calc import add
Anser = add(a)
print(Anser)
```

**Powershell**

```
$a = 5
python.exe main.py $a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershellの変数とPythonの変数は全く別のものです。
PowershellからPythonを呼び出した時には、コマンドライン引数を`sys.argv`などの命令で取得する必要があります。

また`sys.argv`は引数を文字列型の配列で保持していますので、値を適切な型にキャストします。
`main.py`を下記のように修正すると動作するはずです。

```
from calc import add
import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
Anser = add(a)
print(Anser)
```

Comment: 自力でちょうどsys.argvに行き着いたところでした。てっきり変数の渡し方が同じだとばかり思っていたので混乱してしまいました。思っていた通りに関数を実行することができました